# Почему react-hook-form отправляет весь стейт а не то что выбрал пользователь?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

я не могу понять почему форма отправляет весь стейт и как сделать чтобы отправлялось только то, что выбрал юзер? также для селекта использую React-Select

```
const [dataBase] = useState([{
        city: [
            {id: 1, label: 'Харьков', value: "Харьков"},
            {id: 2, label: 'Киев', value: "Киев"},
            {id: 3, label: 'Львов', value: "Львов"},
            {id: 4, label: 'Днепр', value: "Днепр"},
            {id: 5, label: 'Запорожье', value: "Запорожье"}
        ]
    }])

    const [currentCity, setCurrentCity] = useState('Харьков')

    const getValueCity = () => {
        return currentCity ? dataBase[0].city.find(c => c.value === currentCity) : ''
    }

    const onChangeCity = (newValue) => {
        setCurrentCity(newValue.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (data) => { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) 
    }

   return {
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Select
              {...register("city")}
              placeholder={'Выбери город'}
              options={dataBase[0].city}
              className={styles.selectCity}
              value={getValueCity()}
              onChange={onChangeCity}
           />
           <input className={styles.input} type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Где тут вы используете react-hook-form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас неверно записан currentCity, Вам нужно сделать так

```
const [currentCity, setCurrentCity] = useState(dataBase[0].city[0])
```

И заменить

```
const getValueCity = () => currentCity || dataBase[0].city.find(c => c.value === currentCity.value)
```

Также у Вас странный submit, смените его на

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```